# LetsEncrypt renewal fails:Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.. Skipping.AFTER I STOPPED APACHE2

Tags: ssl, certbot-external-auth

I am using apache2 in Debian10, I'm trying to update an SSL certificate with the command certbot, but i faced this problem. after I looked other question, It seems like the port 80 has been used by other Program.
I have used command

```
systemctl stop apache2.service
```

to stop the apache2, but it was nothing changed.
then I used `lsof -i:80` to show the list

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 6028     root    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6029 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6030 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6031 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6032 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6035 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6038 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6039 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6042 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6043 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6045 www-data    4u  IPv6 320155      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

I killed them, but It is come out after I use command

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

please teach me how to fix it, thank you.